# laravel multiple variables in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, eloquent

I am trying to include two variables that are looping through an array in one foreach loop in my view to display the win and loss record for a given team for that year. If the same empty array can be used for both then cool, but that's not what I'm here for...

```
public function show($id)
    {
       $seasons =( [ 2005, 2006,2007,
            2008,
            2009,
            2010,
            2011,
            2012,
            2013,
            2014,
           2015,
           2016]);

          $seasonFinalWins=[];
          $seasonFinalLosses=[];


        foreach($seasons as $homeFinalWin) {
            $seasonFinalWins[$homeFinalWin]=GameData::where('team', $id)->
            where('win', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $homeFinalWin)
            ->count();
           }

           foreach($seasons as $homeFinalLoss) {
            $seasonFinalLosses[$homeFinalLoss]=GameData::where('team', $id)->
            where('loss', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $homeFinalLoss)
            ->count();
           }
```

View

```
 @if($seasonFinalWins)
 @foreach($seasonFinalWins as $seasonFinalWin)
  <td>{{$seasonFinalWin}}</td>
 @endforeach
 @endif
```

How do I include the $seasonFinalLosses in my foreach in the above View?

I have experimented with combining ...

```
 $finalRecords=([$seasonFinalLosses, $seasonFinalWins]);
```

and View...

```
 @if($finalRecords)
 @foreach($finalRecords as $finalRecord)
  <td>{{$finalRecord->$seasonFinalWins}}</td>
 @endforeach
 @endif
```

but I got an array to String error. I need to know if there is a way to make it so both variables can be called upon the same foreach through a -> or any other means?

To be clear, I have the Wins column showing up for each year, but I need a way to  include the losses on the same . Thanks.

Comment: It would really be a helping wing for you to use eloquent relations between the teams and their gamedatas. The model methods provided by laravel's eloquent are really going to make the extracting and sorting out of the information you need extremely simplier, take a look on that. If you need any further advice/help, drop a response, we could provide a simple guide.

Comment: please append and show `GameData` class and fields

Comment: I can look into that route, but is there no way to include two variables like I am asking? I really hate to abandon this completely when I am on the verge of seemingly making it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use this code. I hope useful for you:

`getMessagesFor` method :

```
public function getMessagesFor(Request $request)
{

    $seasons = [ 2005, 2006,2007,
        2008,
        2009,
        2010,
        2011,
        2012,
        2013,
        2014,
        2015,
        2016];

    $seasonFinal=[];
    foreach($seasons as $session) {
        $seasonFinal['win'][$session]=GameData::where('team', $id)->where('win', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $session)
            ->count();
        $seasonFinal['loss'][$session]=GameData::where('team', $id)->
        where('loss', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $session)
            ->count();
    }


return view('welcome3',compact('seasonFinal'));

}
```

`welcome3` view :

```
<table border="1">

@if($seasonFinal)
    @foreach($seasonFinal as $key=>$years)
        <td>type : {{$key}}</td>
        <td>count </td>
        @foreach($years as $year=>$count)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$year}}</td>
                <td>{{$count}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endif

</table>
```

result :

[image]

```html
<table border="1">

                        <tbody><tr><td>type : win</td>
            <td>count </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                    <td>2005</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2006</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2007</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2008</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2009</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2010</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2011</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2012</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2014</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                                <tr><td>type : loss</td>
            <td>count </td>
                            </tr><tr>
                    <td>2005</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2006</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2007</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2008</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2009</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2010</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2011</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2012</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2013</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2014</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2015</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                            <tr>
                    <td>2016</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                </tr>
                        
</tbody></table>
```

If necessary, you can create different styles and modes for your table.

for example this is another model :

`getMessagesFor` method :

```
public function getMessagesFor(Request $request)
{

    $seasons = [ 2005, 2006,2007,
        2008,
        2009,
        2010,
        2011,
        2012,
        2013,
        2014,
        2015,
        2016];

    $seasonFinal=[];
    foreach($seasons as $session) {
        $seasonFinal[$session]['win']=GameData::where('team', $id)->where('win', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $session)
            ->count();
        $seasonFinal[$session]['loss']=GameData::where('team', $id)->
        where('loss', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $session)
            ->count();
    }


return view('welcome3',compact('seasonFinal'));

}
```

`welcome3` view :

```
<table border="1">

@if($seasonFinal)
    <tr>
        <td>year  </td>
        <td> win count</td>
        <td> loss count</td>
    </tr>
    @foreach($seasonFinal as $year=>$value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$year}}</td>
            <td> {{$value['win']}}</td>
            <td> {{$value['loss']}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif

</table>
```

result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_merge`

```
$finalRecords = array_merge($seasonFinalLosses, $seasonFinalWins);
```

Comment: Hello, when I do this and correct my view to  ATif($finalRecords)
     ATforeach($finalRecords as $finalRecord)
      <td>{{$finalRecord}}</td>
     ATendforeach
     ATendif

I get an Array to string conversion error if I try to  <td>{{$finalRecord->$seasonFinalLosses}}</td>

I am looking to include both variables in the same foreach so that it can loop through each variable and display each number on the same line in my view.

Comment: @Bw70316 use `dd($finalRecords)` to see yout data

Comment: I reached a solution. Thanks for your help and input!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this through some help on laravel FB page....

Controller

```
            $seasons =( [ 2005, 2006,2007,
            2008,
            2009,
            2010,
            2011,
            2012,
            2013,
            2014,
           2015,
           2016]);



           $seasonFinalWins=[];
           $seasonFinalLosses=[];

    foreach($seasons as $homeFinalWin) {
            $seasonFinalWins[$homeFinalWin]=GameData::where('team', $id)->
            where('win', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $homeFinalWin)
            ->count();
           }

           foreach($seasons as $homeFinalLoss) {
            $seasonFinalLosses[$homeFinalLoss]=GameData::where('team', $id)->
            where('loss', '1')
            ->where('stage', 'R16')
            ->where('round', 'final')
            ->where('year', $homeFinalLoss)
            ->count();
           }
```

View

```
     <th scope="row">Finals Appearances</th>


@if(isset($seasonFinalWins) && isset($seasonFinalLosses))
  @foreach($seasonFinalWins as $key => $sfn)
    <td>{{$sfn}}-{{$seasonFinalLosses[$key]}}</td>
  @endforeach
@endif
```

NOTE: Not sure if the variables with an empty array are necessary, but the person who helped me with this code included them.